# Powershell getting the Contents of a Windows Word Table with PSWriteWord

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I'm trying to access a table in a docx file with powershell.
I tried using PSWriteWord to get the contents but it only shows me the whole unformated 'backround code' like this (see end).

Is there a way I can acces the table contents, so that I could use them to fill a diffrent table?

I'm trying to format a journal I'm getting from a tutor into a format I'm using in my own Journal respectively paste the contens of one table into another but automated.

```
Import-Module PSWriteWord

Get-WordTable -WordDocument (Get-WordDocument C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Journal_VU6-FIAE_KW11_14032022-20032022.docx) -TableID 0


Paragraphs            : {Normal, Normal, Normal, Normal...}
Pictures              : {}
Hyperlinks            : {}
RowCount              : 20
ColumnCount           : 5
Rows                  : {Xceed.Document.NET.Row, Xceed.Document.NET.Row, Xceed.Document.NET.Row, Xceed.Document.NET.Row...}
Alignment             : left
AutoFit               : Fixed
Design                : None
Index                 : 224
CustomTableDesignName : 
TableCaption          : 
TableDescription      : 
TableLook             : Xceed.Document.NET.TableLook
ColumnWidths          : {1346, 709, 4851, 1669...}
Xml                   : <w:tbl xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
                          <w:tblPr>
                            <w:tblW w:w="9568" w:type="dxa" />
                            <w:tblBorders>
                              <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
                              <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
                              <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
                              <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
                              <w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
                              <w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
                            </w:tblBorders>
                            <w:tblLayout w:type="fixed" />
                            <w:tblCellMar>
                              <w:left w:w="70" w:type="dxa" />
                              <w:right w:w="70" w:type="dxa" />
                            </w:tblCellMar>
                            <w:tblLook w:val="0000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="0" />
                          </w:tblPr>
                          <w:tblGrid>
                            <w:gridCol w:w="1346" />
                            <w:gridCol w:w="709" />
                            <w:gridCol w:w="4851" />
                            <w:gridCol w:w="1669" />
                            <w:gridCol w:w="993" />
                          </w:tblGrid>
                          <w:tr w:rsidR="00B11417" w:rsidRPr="00761CEC" w:rsidTr="009C5764">
                            <w:trPr>
                              <w:cantSplit />
                              <w:trHeight w:hRule="exact" w:val="600" />
                            </w:trPr>
                            <w:tc>
                              <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="1346" w:type="dxa" />
                                <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
                                <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
                              </w:tcPr>
                              <w:p w:rsidR="00B11417" w:rsidRPr="00DB574D" w:rsidRDefault="00B11417">
                                <w:pPr>
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                    <w:sz w:val="22" />
                                    <w:szCs w:val="22" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                </w:pPr>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="00DB574D">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                    <w:sz w:val="22" />
                                    <w:szCs w:val="22" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:t>Montag</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                              </w:p>
                            </w:tc>
                            <w:tc>
                              <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="709" w:type="dxa" />
                                <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
                              </w:tcPr>
                              <w:p w:rsidR="00B11417" w:rsidRPr="00761CEC" w:rsidRDefault="00B11417">
                                <w:pPr>
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                </w:pPr>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="00761CEC">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:t>1.</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r w:rsidR="00252AB3" w:rsidRPr="00761CEC">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:t>/2.</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="00761CEC">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:t xml:space="preserve"> UE</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                              </w:p>
                            </w:tc>
                            <w:tc>
                              <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4851" w:type="dxa" />
                                <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
                              </w:tcPr>
                              <w:p w:rsidR="00A93021" w:rsidRDefault="00A93021" w:rsidP="00A93021">
                                <w:pPr>
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                    <w:sz w:val="18" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                </w:pPr>
                                <w:r>
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                    <w:sz w:val="18" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:t>Begrüßung / Vorstellung</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                              </w:p>
                              <w:p w:rsidR="00B11417" w:rsidRPr="00761CEC" w:rsidRDefault="00807D31" w:rsidP="00A93021">
                                <w:pPr>
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                </w:pPr>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="00A93021">
                                  <w:rPr>
                                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                                    <w:sz w:val="18" />
                                  </w:rPr>
                                  <w:t>Strom, Stromrichtung, Reihenschaltung, Parallelschaltung</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                              </w:p>
                            </w:tc>
                            <w:tc> ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have module `PSWriteWord`, but you could use the COM Word.Application object for this if you have Word installed.
Read the data from the table and create an in-memory CSV from that.

```
$filename = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Journal_VU6-FIAE_KW11_14032022-20032022.docx'

$objWord = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$objTable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$maxCols  = $objTable.Columns.Count
$maxRows  = $objTable.Rows.Count

# read the data from each cell and join the cell values with a comma to create CSV format
$data = for ($row = 1; $row -le $maxRows; $row++) {
    $line = for ($col = 1; $col -le $maxCols; $col++) {
        # remove the `0D07` control characters Word adds and double all quotes in the field if applicable
        '"{0}"' -f ($objTable.Cell($row,$col).Range.Text -replace '\p{Cc}+' -replace '"', '""')
    }
    $line -join ','
}

$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objDocument)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objTable)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()


# finally convert the in-memory CSV data into an array of objects
$result = $data | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

<sup>Regex Unicode Category `\p{Cc}` means a character with the Unicode property “control” (an ASCII 0x00..0x1F or Latin-1 0x80..0x9F control character)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, working with a COM object was my alternative to PSWriteWord. I guess due to the lack of documentation of the module I just go with this. Your code is a greate input! One question: Do you use the ReleaseComObject Method to clean your memory? I'm pretty new to Powershell.

Comment: @mathis_dukatz Thanks for the nice feedback and Yes, using those `ReleaseComObject()` lines make sure no used COM objects will linger on (use up system resources) when no longer needed. Eventually, the system will clear them, but only after the last reference is gone and you have exited PowerShell (no telling when that will happen..). With ReleaseComObject() the code itself tells the system to go ahead and destroy those memory blocks as soon as it runs its Garbage Collect routine.